# How to export data from cassandra to Json file using Python or other language?

Tags: python, json, cassandra, cqlsh

I want to export data from Cassandra to Json file, because Pentaho didn't support my version of Cassandra 3.10

Comment: There is jdbc driver for Cassandra, so Pentaho could treat Cassandra as typical SQL database. We've used Pentaho+Cassandra in one of our projects though I'm not sure about Cassandra's version.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add `json` after `select` to get your results in json format:

```
cqlsh:cycling> select json name, checkin_id, timestamp from checkin;
 [json]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"name": "BRAND", "checkin_id": "50554d6e-29bb-11e5-b345-feff8194dc9f", "timestamp": "2016-08-28 21:45:10.406Z"}
  {"name": "VOSS", "checkin_id": "50554d6e-29bb-11e5-b345-feff819cdc9f", "timestamp": "2016-08-28 21:44:04.113Z"}
(2 rows)
```

Taken from https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryJSON.html

Comment: But I want json file no just json format, how could I save this json?

Answer (score 2):

DataStax now provides the [tool called DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) that works with both DSE & Cassandra, and it's heavily optimized to load and unload data to/from DSE/Cassandra.  It supports output as JSON format as well, like this:

```
dsbulk unload -k keyspace -t table -url out_dir -c json
```

More examples of unloading data, could be found in [this blog post](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading), that is part of the series of blog posts on DSBulk.  For example, you can specify which columns of the table to offload, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash redirction to get json file.

`cqlsh -e "select JSON * from ${keyspace}.${table}" | awk 'NR>3 {print $0}' | head -n -2 > table.json`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need to export cassandra tables as JSON and built a [command line tool](https://github.com/splink/cpipe) for it: